# Transfer files between Ubuntu vm on esxi 6.0 and windows computer on the same network

Tags: vmware, file-transfer, esxi

I want to transfer a folder from a Ubuntu virtual machine running on a physical device with esxi 6.0 to a windows 10 laptop. I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: The fact, that Ubuntu is running in a VM is of no importance.

Now the transport question:

- If this is a one-off you might want to use `WinSCP` on the Windows side to copy the folder via SFTP/SCP
- If this is a regular operation, you might want to use SMB:
- - either share a folder on the Windows side and mount it on the Ubuntu side
- - or install `samba` on the Ubuntu VM and mount it on the Windows side.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by sharing the folder on Ubuntu and on filer explorer in Windows i would type

\\"the ip of the Ubuntu machine"\"name of shared folder".